# Alarm Manager - triggers after every 2 hours

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have following piece of code which gets called once. However notification gets triggered after every 2 hours where as I want it to get triggered after 2 days. I tried all options, but still its not working

```
public int setAlarm(){
    Calendar Calendar_Object = Calendar.getInstance();
    /*
        Calendar_Object.set(Calendar.MONTH,6);
        Calendar_Object.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);
        Calendar_Object.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 18);*/

            // MyView is my current Activity, and AlarmReceiver is the
        // BoradCastReceiver
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Splash.this, TimeAlarm.class);

           PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
                    0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

            long wkupTime = Calendar_Object.getTimeInMillis() + 36000; 


        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
//      Log.w("alarm set for " , Calendar_Object.getTime().toString ());

        /*
         * The following sets the Alarm in the specific time by getting the long
         * value of the alarm date time which is in calendar object by calling
         * the getTimeInMillis(). Since Alarm supports only long value , we're
         * using this method.
         */

//      alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, Calendar_Object.getTimeInMillis(),1000 *24*3600,
//              pendingIntent);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, wkupTime , 172800000, pendingIntent);

        return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int setAlarm() {
    Calendar Calendar_Object = Calendar.getInstance();

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Splash.this, TimeAlarm.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
                    0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    long wkupTime = Calendar_Object.getTimeInMillis() + 72000; 

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, wkupTime ,7200000, pendingIntent);

    return 0;
}
```